# R -- correlating multiple text patterns to single references

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data file that has codes that repeat and I need to map these codes to more formal names.  My data file has one column and has the codes that represent an internal agency.... "123", "1234", and "12345" are the codes and repeated multiple times.  Code "123" equals "ABC", code "1234" equals "BCA" and "12345" equals "CAB".  All I want to do is add another column that maps these relationship.

I tried the gsub code below but each instance overwrote the previous command.

`data$agency <- gsub("12345","CAB",data$Code)
data$agency <- gsub("1234","BCA",data$Code)
data$agency <- gsub("123","ABC",data$Code)`

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You should use `data$agency <- gsub("1234","BCA",data$agency)` and `data$agency <- gsub("123","ABC",data$agency)`. There's also likely a better solution overall, so I'd keep the question open for more answers.

Comment: have a look at `match`. Create a lookup table of old codes and new codes and then match them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
install.packages("stringr")

library(stringr)
data$agency <- sapply(data$Code, function(x) str_replace_all(x, c("12345"="CAB","1234"="BCA","123"="ABC")))
```

This will modify all your patterns into their respective replacements for all elements in your vector

Comment: Chi Pak --- Worked perfectly!!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To explain "emilliman5" comment,

```
> data
   agency
1  12345
2   1234
3    123
```

create a new code table as follows:

```
> codeTable
   code value
1   123   ABC
2  1234   BCA
3 12345   CAB
```

and, following command will return your desired results:

```
> data['new_column'] <- codeTable$value[match(data$agency, codeTable$code)]
> data
  agency new_column
1  12345        CAB
2   1234        BCA
3    123        ABC
```

Comment: Sagar and emilliman5 - Thanks for the suggestions and this worked as well.